# Conditional formatting: Showing direction arrows for a series

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm using Excel 2010.

Does anyone have a quicker way of implementing this?:

I have a table, with 2 columns; all I want is a green arrow (upwards) or red arrow (downwards) if the value on the right is bigger/smaller than the value on the left.

Unfortunately I can only get condition formatting to work on each individual cell (so when I have 15+ rows, in theory I would have to create 15 'rules'. Is there a quicker way of creating some sort of series that can be easily replicated?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you actually wanting an arrow, or are you looking for the number to be colored Red or Green depending on the value to the right?

Comment: An upward green arrow if the number on the right is bigger than the number on the left. Or a red downward facing arrow if the number on the right is smaller than the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a helper cell to with something like `=IF(A1>B1,1,0)` and then apply the conditional formatting for the arrows for the whole table. You might need to adjust when what arrow shows up but when I threw it in a sample sheet it worked by default. You can set it to show the icon only too.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I have read your answer several times and I don't really understand it :(

Comment: Just make a 3rd cell with that formula. It will output a 1 or a 0. Apply the conditional formatting for arrows to that column.

Comment: Thank you! Would I just have to mess about with making the number (0 or 1) white in order to hide it? Or is there a way of getting the arrow into the same cell as my original "right column" figure.

Comment: In the conditional format screen there is a checkbox to "show icon only"