# Why is my conditional formatting not working?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, conditional-formatting

Conditional Formatting Rule
[image]

Data

[image]

I want the value under **Total Hours** to be highlighted if it is less than the value under **Expected Hours** for every row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the *Applies to:* is to remain `$E:$E, then the formula should be based on,

`=AND(ROW()>1, $E1<$F1)`

[image: CF Time comaprision]

The additional `ROW()>1` condition is actually not needed for your layout as *Total Hours* is considered greater than *Expected Hours* but if the column label in E1 started with a letter less than the *E* in F1's *Expected Hours* it would actually trigger a false positive.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to use `=E2<F2` in the formula (with **relative references**).

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27666480/2707864) and [note 1 in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27196722/2707864).